# How to prove that this Vector Field is conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-fields

[The vector field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0N2f.png)

Where k is a constant.
Suppose that I am to prove that this vector field is conservative do I have to first calculate
$\vec{F} = \langle \frac{kx}{r^3}, \frac{ky}{r^3},\frac{kz}{r^3}\rangle$

And then use the partial derivative component test to determine whether it is conservative? I find it quite difficult to find the partial derivative of each of the components. All help and tips are very appreciated. Thank you

Update:

This is my attempt, would this be correct? [My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGVoD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F_i=kr^{-3}x_i$, $$\partial_iF_j=k(r^{-3}\delta_{ij}-3r^{-4}x_j\partial_i r)=k(r^{-3}\delta_{ij}-3 r^{-5}x_i x_j)$$is $i\leftrightarrow j$ symmetric, so$$(\nabla\times F)_h=\sum_{ij}\epsilon_{hij}\partial_i F_j=0.$$